# Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.selectBook is not a function, automatic duplication of this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, redux, react-redux

I have come across the exact similar question in Stackoverflow community but, the answer to the question doesn't answer my woes. I have been experiencing this problem after trying almost everything there is related to this problem on the internet. So please answer this so that move ahead in my development. Any help in deeply appreciated.

> **book-list.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index.js';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class BookList extends Component {
    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li
                    key={book.title}
                    onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)}
                    className="list-group-item">
                    {book.title}
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        books: state.books
    };
}

//Anythin returned from this function will end up as props
// on the BookList container
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    // whenever selectBook is called, the result should be passed
    // to all of our reducers
    return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch);
}


//Promote BookList from a component to a container - it needs to know
//about this new dispatch method, selectBook. Make ot available
//as a prop.

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

> **index.js - Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from './reducer_books';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

> **index.js - Actions**

```
function selectBook(book) {
  console.log('A book has been selected', book.title);
}
```

Comment: Are you exporting `selectBook` from your actions file? If you aren't you can't import it.

Comment: You are missing the export in your action. Limenwhat Andy Commented . That should solve your problem

Comment: Ok! can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case (and mine) changing this:

```
function selectBook(book) {
  console.log('A book has been selected', book.title);
}
```

to:

```
export function selectBook(book) {
  console.log('A book has been selected:', book.title);
}
```

is what fixed it. Like the comments on the question, I wasn't exporting selectBook. I wasn't entirely sure how to do that; however this is the correct way.